# Android Map Custom info window with box shape on bottom or top map

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I need to make custom info window for my android application; like ziprealty application. Please see the images below.

This info window appears when user clicked on the marker. It can show on the top of the map or on the bottom of the map according marker position.

I don't have idea to make this. I know from stackoverflow, many ways to create custom info windows, but for this one, I haven't found any solution here. So, can somebody tell me how to build that?

[image: image1]
[image]

Comment: This is not info window..its view which overlays the map.

Comment: @Indiandroid can you give some example or link?